# Failing to combine 2 commands in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to make below PowerShell command work but failing. Anyone know how to get this working?
I know there is something wrong in the Expression tag but don't know what.

```
Get-BrokerDesktop -MaxRecordCount 5000 | Where{($_.LastConnectionUser -eq $null) -and ($_.AssociatedUserNames -ne $null)} | Select MachineName,@{ Name = 'CreationDate';  Expression = {Get-ProvVM -MaxRecordCount 5000 -Filter "VMName -eq $_.HostedMachineName" | Select CreationDate}} | ft -AutoSize
```

It gives only the first column output. There's 2nd column name displayed but no data.
If I run the 2nd command separately as below, I'm getting the output.

```
Get-ProvVM -MaxRecordCount 5000 -Filter "VMName -eq 'ComputerName'" | Select CreationDate
```

`HostedMachineName` is a property of `Get-BrokerDesktop`.
`VMName` is a property of `Get-ProvVM`.

Comment: It just seems like `-Filter` is not used correctly. Most commands expect the filter value to be a string. Powershell will not tokenize your filter correctly as a string.

Comment: Unsure of the objects returned from these commands but maybe try: `$(Get-ProvVM -MaxRecordCount 5000 -Filter (VMName -eq $_.HostedMachineName)).CreationDate`

Comment: @mjsqu, thank you for the suggestion but it didn't work :-(

Comment: @AdminOfThings, if `-Filter` is not the way ahead, I can use `Where` also.

Comment: When comparing to $null, it should always appear first (e.g. '$null -eq ...'): https://rencore.com/blog/powershell-null-comparison/

Comment: @Graham, I don't know what's the context of `null` here. There's no null. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think @AdminOfThings is correct about the syntax for `-Filter`. Should be `-Filter "VMName -eq 'ComputerName'"`

Comment: @Theo, that was an edit mistake from my end, I have corrected it but as I wrote already, instead of `-Filter` I can use `While` also. The corrected one also doesn't work.

Comment: Try `"VMName -eq '$($_.HostedMachineName)'"`

Comment: "$_.AssociatedUserNames -ne $null" => "$null -eq $_.AssociatedUserNames", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Theo, thank you, your solution worked but I had to add `-ExpandProperty` to make it as I want. Here's my final command that is working exactly as intended.

```
Get-BrokerDesktop -MaxRecordCount 5000 | Where{($_.LastConnectionUser -eq $null) -and ($_.AssociatedUserNames -ne $null)} | Select MachineName,@{ Name = 'CreationDate';  Expression = {Get-ProvVM -MaxRecordCount 5000 -Filter "VMName -eq '$($_.HostedMachineName)'" | Select CreationDate -ExpandProperty CreationDate}} | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Good job! However, I would capture the outcome of this in a variable and do a `ft -AutoSize` later on that variable. That way you can do more with the result than just output in the console. Also, the `Select` could be shortened to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty CreationDate`

Comment: @Theo, thank you again for your suggestion, however this command is a part of a bigger fragment and I have a couple of other fragments too. So, I would keep it that way.